# How to include the routes of React to django?

Tags: django, reactjs

I am working on a varsity project which is a web based application.It uses React as frontend and django as backend.
Here is my app.js..

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="signin/"  exact component={Signin} />
        <Route path="signin/signup/"  component={SignUp} />
     </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

my django base urls looks like..

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^dream11/', include('core.urls')),
    url(r'^api/', include('api.urls')),
    url(r'^api-token-auth/$', views.obtain_auth_token, name="token" )
]
```

when i'm going to dream11/signin/ link , django is not showing anything.it gives me the error,

```
Using the URLconf defined in Dream11v3.urls, Django tried these URL 
patterns, in this order:

^admin/
^dream11/ ^$ [name='index']
^api/
^api-token-auth/$ [name='token']
The current path, dream11/signin/, didn't match any of these.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You need to show us the core/urls.py so we can see what is supposed to be available under /dream11/.

Comment: that includes empty string to point to home page..actually /dream11/ is the home page